# how to get row index in cellTemplate of angular ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

`ng-click="grid.appScope.selectItem($event,row.entity.$index);"` i want to pass row index through this function. Even if i tried with $index,$parent.$index. I am unable to get the index.

Comment: `<tr ng-repeat="cells in CouponsList.CellPhones">
<td><button  ng-click="doStuff($index+1)">{{cells.localVendorAddress}}</button></td>` Its supposed to be like this... You need an iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `rowRenderIndex` or  `$parent.$index`

```
ng-click="grid.appScope.selectItem($event, rowRenderIndex);"
```

or

```
ng-click="grid.appScope.selectItem($event, $parent.$index);"
```

Comment: cool, `rowRenderIndex` its working for me. thanks. even if i tried with `grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.indexOf(row)`

Comment: @Akhil Please accept this answer if it resolved your issue

Comment: so if I have that click event in a child hierarchy then should I do like `$parent.$parent.$index`?

Comment: `rowRenderIndex ` is returning the index of visible row only